# Cambiar estado de un botón para interactuar con menu web

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Me  explico tengo una página web en la que debo interactuar con los elementos de un menu y debo mostrarlos y ocultarlos, en funcion de la opcion que elija en una tabla en una página aparte, en esta tabla cada uno de los items, debería tener dos opciones, activar y desactivar para cada item dado.

Por ejemplo en mi web tengo un menu que tiene varias secciones, la seccion de contactenos, la seccion de noticias y la seccion de blog. si desde este menú deseo mostrar las categorias contactenos y blog en esta página debo elegir que el boton activar de la página de la tabla se muestre y por lo tanto desactivar se oculte.

Por el momento no tengo programado dicho menú web, pero estoy empezando con la página de configuración y quiero programar que me salga la opción de activar o desactivar de forma que después pueda trabajar con esta opción y asignarla a mi menú en otra página.

Tengo este código:

```js
//seleccion ID
    let noticiasCambio = $("a#noticiasActivar");
    let noticiasDesactivar = $("a#noticiasDesactivar");
    let contactoCambio = $("a#contactoActivar");
    let contactoDesactivar = $("a#contactoDesactivar");
    let blogCambio = $("a#blogActivar");
    let blogDesactivar = $("a#blogDesactivar");
    //configuracion de las acciones de los botones
    $(function() {
    //blog
    if ($(blogCambio).length > 0) {
            $('a').click(blogCambio, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("hola");
                blogCambio.removeClass('btn btn-info').addClass('btn btn-danger').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'blogDesactivar').html('Activar');
            });
        } else if ($(blogDesactivar).length > 0 && $(blogoCambio).length < 0) {
            $('a').click(blogDesactivar, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("adios");
                blogDesactivar.removeClass('btn btn-danger').addClass('btn btn-info').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'blogActivar').html('Desactivar');
            });
        }
    //contacto
    if ($(contactoCambio).length > 0) {
            $('a').click(contactoCambio, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("hola");
                contactoCambio.removeClass('btn btn-info').addClass('btn btn-danger').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'contactoDesactivar').html('Activar');
            });
        } else if ($(contactoDesactivar).length > 0 && $(contactoCambio).length < 0) {
            $('a').click(contactoDesactivar, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("adios");
                contactoDesactivar.removeClass('btn btn-danger').addClass('btn btn-info').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'contactoActivar').html('Desactivar');
            });
        }
        //noticias
        if ($(noticiasCambio).length > 0) {
            $('a').click(noticiasCambio, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("hola");
                noticiasCambio.removeClass('btn btn-info').addClass('btn btn-danger').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'noticiasDesactivar').html('Activar');
            });
        } else if ($(noticiasDesactivar).length > 0 && $(noticiasCambio).length < 0) {
            $('a').click(noticiasDesactivar, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("adios");
                noticiasDesactivar.removeClass('btn btn-danger').addClass('btn btn-info').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'noticiasActivar').html('Desactivar');
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-lg-11">
    <h2>Configuracion</h2>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Opciones</th>
        <th width="200px">Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Blog
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="" id="blogActivar">Desactivar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Contactenos
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="" id="contactoActivar">Desactivar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Noticias
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-info" href="" id="noticiasActivar">Desactivar</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pero no funciona de forma adecuada, ya que si pulsas un boton , hace el mismo resultado para los demás botones y a continuación si pulsamos activar nunca funciona.
Como podría conseguir este efecto de forma que depués pudiera seguir trabajando con algún tipo de variable o algo similar para asignarle a mi futuro menú para mostrarlo u ocultarlo?

Comment: Hola, @WinterIsback. No acabo de entender qué es lo que quieres lograr. Mi impresión es que quieres tener una tabla en un panel de administración (¿la página aparte?) que activa o desactiva determinados enlaces para mostrar en el menú de una app (de forma global, para todos los usuarios). En la app, el menú debe contener los enlaces que están marcados como activo en la tabla. ¿Es así?

Comment: si, yo tengo la web por un lado y una tabla de administración donde hay cada nombre del menu de la web y lo activo o desactivo desde aqui para que se muestre o no en mi web

Comment: Entonces parece que tienes que administrar el menú por un lado (establecer en el backend las opciones) y generar el menú dinámicamente a partir de las opciones del backend o mediante AYAX (yo te recomendaría la primera opción). En cualquier caso, el tratamiento es totalmente distinto a lo que planteas ya que tienes que obtener del backend los datos.

Comment: como puedo hacer esto no tengo mucha idea, mi idea era crear la página como tal y hacer que los botones funcionaran y en base al estado del boton que se mostrara o no en el menú, pero la verdad que estoy perdida

Comment: La explicación excede con mucho el espacio de una pregunta. Te recomiendo que leas algo sobre backends (en PHP, por ejemplo, que es un lenguaje suficientemente sencillo para empezar).

Comment: Vale gracias a ver si trato de hacerlo de otra forma distinta tal vez crear una tabla y asignarle estados y si esta activo o desactivado que recoja a variable y lo muestre o no?